# Open cover generalization of the Tube Lemma

Tags: general-topology

**Tube Lemma (via open covers):**  Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces with $Y$ compact and let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X \times Y$. Then for each $x \in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $W$ of $x$ and a finite collection $\mathscr{U}_0 \subset \mathscr{U}$ so that $W \times Y$ is contained in $\bigcup \mathscr{U}_0$.

The statement of this variant of the Tube Lemma replaces the idea of a superset containing the tube with an finite collection of open subsets whose union is a superset of the tube.

I've not seen this version of the Tube Lemma anywhere. Does anyone have any advice on how to prove it? Would the proof be made the "same" as other proofs where no such open cover is required or does this version require a different proof entirely? What's a good place to start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make precise what you mean. $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X \times Y$, what is the *finite subcover* $\mathscr{U}_0 \subset \mathscr{U}$  supposed to cover? Is $\mathscr{U}_0$ just a *finite subset* of $\mathscr{U}$ which covers $W \times Y$?

Comment: @PaulFrost I have edited the statement of the problem. I mean to say that $\mathscr{U}_0$ is just a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $W \times Y$. So yes you are understanding correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is more or less the same as that of the "usual" tube lemma. Since $S_x = \{x\} \times Y$ is compact, there exists a finite subset $\mathscr{U}_0 \subset \mathscr{U}$  covering $S_x$. Let $V  = \bigcup \mathscr{U}_0$. Via the known tube lemma we find an open neighborhood $W$ of $x$ such that $W \times Y \subset V = \bigcup \mathscr{U}_0$.